# Closed form $\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{\ln (\sqrt{3} x +2)}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}} (\sqrt{3} x + 2)^{n}}\ dx$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, improper-integrals, closed-form

Does the following integral 
$$\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{\ln (\sqrt{3} x +2)}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}} (\sqrt{3} x + 2)^{n}}\ dx, \; \; n \in \mathbb{N}$$

have a nice closed form? Basically I cannot tackle it in any direction. Symmetry is useless . Applyig parts , well , gets things worse than they actually are. Could complex analysis help us here? That is, integrating around a dog bone contour ... I highly doubt it but it is just a thought.

Any help on this one?

Comment: Do you have reason to believe there is a closed form of answer?

Comment: Well, I actually do not have a specific reason. That is why I am asking the question. The original question I was trying to solve was:

$$\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{\ln (\sqrt{3} x +2)}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}} (\sqrt{3} x + 2)^{2}}\ dx$$

and for this one I still have no progress. The value of this integral is:

$$2\pi\left(\log2-\log3-\frac{1}{2} \right)$$

but I do not know how to get it.

Comment: By the way I also tried the Feymann trick by inserting a parameter $a>0$ in the integral, that is:

$$\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{\ln (\sqrt{3} x a +2)}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}} (\sqrt{3} x + 2)^{2}}\ dx$$

but I think things get much more complicated. The derivative appears not have such a clear formula or it is very difficult by hand to get it. W|A cannot  seem to find a form for the derivative. 

Let's see if someone has a clever idea.

Comment: This never hurts, @Cleo

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's integrate by $n$ first:
$$
K(n) = \int I(n) dn = \int \int_{-1}^1 \frac{\log(\sqrt{3}x+2)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}(\sqrt{3}x+2)^n} dx dn = -\int_{-1}^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}(\sqrt{3}x+2)^n} + C
$$
**Long path. (original)**
According to Wolfram *Mathematica*
$$
K(n) = -\int_{-1}^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}(\sqrt{3}x+2)^n} + C = -\frac{\pi}{2^n} \,{_2F_1}\left(\frac{n}{2},\frac{n+1}{2};1;\frac{3}{4}\right) + C.
$$
So $$
I(n) = K'(n) = \frac{\pi \log 2}{2^n} {_2F_1}\left(\frac{n}{2},\frac{n+1}{2};1;\frac{3}{4}\right) -\\
-\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}\left(
\frac{\partial _2F_1}{\partial a}\left(\frac{n}{2},\frac{n+1}{2};1;\frac{3}{4}\right) +
\frac{\partial _2F_1}{\partial b}\left(\frac{n}{2},\frac{n+1}{2};1;\frac{3}{4}\right)
\right)
$$
Let
$$G(n,z) = \frac{1}{2^{n}}{_2F_1}\left(\frac{n}{2},\frac{n+1}{2};1;z\right)
$$
Or rewriting in terms of Legendre functions (A&S 15.4.10)
$$
G(n,z) = \left(\frac{1}{4-4z}\right)^{n/2} P_{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-z}}\right)\\
G\left(n,\frac{3}{4}\right) = P_{n-1}\left(2\right)
$$
**Short path.** Note that
$$
P_\lambda(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi (x + \sqrt{x^2 - 1}\cos \theta)^\lambda dx = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi (x + \sqrt{x^2 - 1}\cos \theta)^\lambda dx.
$$
And
$$
\int_{-1}^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}(\sqrt{3}x+2)^n} = \int_{0}^\pi \frac{d\theta}{(2+\sqrt{3}\cos \theta)^n} = \pi P_{-n}(2) = \pi P_{n-1}(2)
$$

Next, following this [paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10910-011-9826-3) and this [paper](https://archive.org/stream/messengerofmathe4849cambuoft#page/124/mode/2up)
$$
\frac{\partial P_{\nu}(z)}{\partial \nu}\Big|_{\nu = n} = -P_n(z) \log\frac{z+1}{2} + \frac{1}{2^{n-1}n!}\frac{d^n}{dz^n} \left[
(z^2-1)\log \frac{z+1}{2}
\right]
$$
so
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial n} G\left(n, \frac{3}{4}\right) = 
-P_{n-1}(2) \log\frac{3}{2} + \frac{1}{2^{n-2}(n-1)!}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}} \left[
(z^2-1)^{n-1}\log \frac{z+1}{2}
\right]_{z=2}
$$
And finally
$$
I(n) = \pi P_{n-1}(2) \log\frac{3}{2} - \frac{\pi}{2^{n-2}(n-1)!}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}} \left[
(z^2-1)^{n-1}\log \frac{z+1}{2}
\right]_{z=2} = -\pi A_n \log\frac{3}{2} - \pi B_n
$$
Here's a table for some $n$:
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & A_n & B_n \\\hline
0 & -1 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 0 \\
2 & 2 & 1 \\
3 & \frac{11}{2} & \frac{15}{4} \\
4 & 17 & \frac{77}{6} \\
5 & \frac{443}{8} & \frac{4213}{96} \\
6 & \frac{743}{4} & \frac{36353}{240} \\
7 & \frac{10159}{16} & \frac{168833}{320} \\
8 & \frac{17593}{8} & \frac{2074197}{1120} \\
9 & \frac{984467}{128} & \frac{234465461}{35840} \\
10 & \frac{1734443}{64} & \frac{3746664781}{161280} \\
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Just a partial answer. I've found closed-form expressions for $n=0,\dots,4$.

$$I(n) := \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{\ln (\sqrt{3} x +2)}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}} (\sqrt{3} x + 2)^{n}}\ dx, \; \; n \in \mathbb{N}.$$

Then these are the following:
\begin{align}
I(0) &= -\pi\ln\left(\frac{2}{3}\right),\\
I(1) &= \pi\ln\left(\frac{2}{3}\right),\\
I(2) &= 2\pi\ln\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)-\pi,\\
I(3) &= \frac{11\pi}{2}\ln\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)-\frac{15\pi}{4},\\
I(4) &= 17\pi\ln\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)-\frac{77\pi}{6}.
\end{align}

I've conjectured that the general form is $a\pi\ln(2/3)+b\pi$ for some rational $a,b$ constans, but with [PSLQ algorithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PSLQAlgorithm.html) I've found nothing more. After all, I think there's a chance to find closed-form for this integral.

Comment: How have you calculated the integrals? W|A does not present a result, only a numerical approach, neither does Maple.